# How do I generate an IT Admin code to enroll devices

Tags: device-administrator

I want to setup a work profile on several devices but I need to be an IT Admin to do that and generate an IT admin code.

How do I do that?

I have about 3 devices that I wish to enroll.

[image]

Comment: I think this is off-topic as you need to get that information from Google Workspace (was known as G-Suite). Given that the product targets small / mid-size business there should be Youtube videos to assist. Also specific questions about Google Workspace is probably more appropriate in [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) which covers IT admin for business.

Comment: Thank you for the advice.  Do you have the ability to move my question to ServerFault or can I?

Comment: Better ask directly in Google forums. For device management IMHO ServerFault is the wrong address, as there is no server involved. And if you open up a question there most likely to will get closed  when they read "Android" in it.

Comment: Is there a Google stack exchange?

Comment: Hi, sorry that this question is off-topic since it's more about enterprise-level device management rather than operating Android itself. [Android Enterprise help](https://support.google.com/work/android/answer/7168897) might have a clue for this. And unfortunately, there's also no Google Stack Exchange.